Docker: SIGTERM SIGINT Signals are sometimes randomly not properly passed to program
We are using the gitlab runner docker executor for the test pipeline of our program:
@pytest.mark.parametrize('mpi',[False,pytest.param(True,marks=[pytest.mark.xfail,pytest.mark.cifail])])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('signal',[sg.SIGUSR1,sg.SIGUSR2,sg.SIGINT])
def test_grid_signals(self,tmp_path,signal):

    match = re.compile(r' <program output where I would like to test SIG Interrupt>', re.U)
    cmd = f'my_program'

    start = time.time()
    log.debug(f'Launching Program: {cmd}')
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                         cwd=tmp_path,env=env,text=True,start_new_session=True)

    while p.poll() is None and time.time()-start<30:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        log.debug(line)
        if re.search(match, line):
            log.debug(f'found match, sending signal {signal}')
            p.send_signal(signal)
            time.sleep(1)
            break
    log.debug('Waiting for process to terminate...')
    p.wait(30)
    log.debug('Process terminated')
    assert p.returncode == 0

This all works fine if run directly on bare metal. However, when we run this in a docker container, these tests sometimes randomly fail for any signal:
        while p.poll() is None and time.time()-start<30:
            line = p.stdout.readline()
            log.debug(line)
            if re.search(match, line):
                log.debug(f'found match, sending signal {signal}')
                p.send_signal(signal)
                time.sleep(1)
                break
        log.debug('Waiting for process to terminate...')
>       p.wait(30)
test_grid_signals.py:56: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:1209: in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
self = <Popen: returncode: None args: ['DAMASK_grid', '-l', 'tensionX.yaml', '-g', ...>, timeout = 30
    def _wait(self, timeout):
        """Internal implementation of wait() on POSIX."""
        if self.returncode is not None:
            return self.returncode
    
        if timeout is not None:
            endtime = _time() + timeout
            # Enter a busy loop if we have a timeout.  This busy loop was
            # cribbed from Lib/threading.py in Thread.wait() at r71065.
            delay = 0.0005 # 500 us -> initial delay of 1 ms
            while True:
                if self._waitpid_lock.acquire(False):
                    try:
                        if self.returncode is not None:
                            break  # Another thread waited.
                        (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(os.WNOHANG)
                        assert pid == self.pid or pid == 0
                        if pid == self.pid:
                            self._handle_exitstatus(sts)
                            break
                    finally:
                        self._waitpid_lock.release()
                remaining = self._remaining_time(endtime)
                if remaining <= 0:
>                   raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, timeout)
E                   subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '['DAMASK_grid', '-l', 'tensionX.yaml', '-g', 'test.vti', '-m', 'material.yaml', '-j', 'test_tensionX']' timed out after 30 seconds
/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:1951: TimeoutExpired

We are using tini to facilitate proper signal processing. There are also no obstructive or zombie processes active before the signal failure:
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  1 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/tini -- sh -c if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then ?exec /usr/local/bin/bash  elif [ -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then ?exec /usr/bin/bash  elif [ -x /bin/bash ]; t
  7 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/bash
 11 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/bash
791 ?        Rl     0:36 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/pytest -s -k not compile and grid
3442 ?        R      0:00 ps -ax

The tricky part is that this only happens sometimes, about 40% of the cases, so it's difficult to reliably replicate. Is there anything that can be done to reliably run this test in docker?
